# Can we update the property of existing nodes and edges of a graph in AWS Neptune using S3 Bulk uploader

Tags: amazon-s3, gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I know using S3 CSV Bulk uploader we can create new vertexes and edges in AWS Neptune GraphDB. What I want to know if it is possible to update some of the properties of a edges and nodes in the Neptune graph using the S3 CSV bulk uploader.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the bulk loader can be used to update properties, but only in the case where properties are of single cardinality [1].  In Neptune, properties are set cardinality by default.  If you're CSV files have the proper header specification (see example below), then you can set the `updateSingleCardinalityProperties` parameter to `TRUE` on the bulk load API request and this will allow the bulk loader to update these properties.

Here's an example of how this would look.  If I have the following CSV file for my vertices (note the header format [2] for defining a single cardinality property):

```
~id,~label,name:String(single),address:String(single)
test001,test-label,John Doe,"101 Elm St.  Herndon, VA"
test002,test-label,Jane Doe,
test002,test-label,,"321 Main St.  Ashburn, VA"
test001,test-label,John Dox,"504 Congress Ave.  McLean, VA"
```

And if I issue the following API request with the `updateSingleCardinalityProperties` parameter set to `TRUE`:

```
curl -X POST \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
https://$NEPTUNE_CLUSTER_ENDPOINT:$NEPTUNE_CLUSTER_PORT/loader -d ‘
{
"source" : "s3://somes3bucket/dl-testload/testload.csv",
"format" : "csv",
"iamRoleArn" : "'$NEPTUNE_LOAD_FROM_S3_ROLE_ARN'",
"region" : "us-west-2",
"failOnError" : "FALSE",
"parallelism" : "OVERSUBSCRIBE",
"updateSingleCardinalityProperties" : "TRUE"
}‘
```

The output of this bulk load would look like:

```
[{'name': ['John Dox'],
  <T.label: 4>: 'test-label',
  'address': ['504 Congress Ave.  McLean, VA'],
  <T.id: 1>: 'test001'},
 {'name': ['Jane Doe'],
  <T.label: 4>: 'test-label',
  'address': ['321 Main St.  Ashburn, VA'],
  <T.id: 1>: 'test002'}]
```

Note how the name and address properties of the test001 vertex were overwritten by the latter row in the CSV file.  This could happen just the same as if that last row were in a different CSV file and part of a latter bulk load job to perform updates.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/load-api-reference-load.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-tutorial-format-gremlin.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's quite helpful just for clarification if we have an existing vertex which is having following properties (with the same header as in your example):    <   test002,test-label,,"321 Main St.  Ashburn, VA"     >    and then we bulk upload a CSV using S3 which has the following entry:  <    test002,test-label,"Jane Doe",      >  now in this case what would be the end properties of this given vertex. would it be       
< test002,test-label,"Jane Doe","321 Main St.  Ashburn, VA"   >   ?

Comment: Correct.  You can append new properties to a vertex in such a manner.